# How to run mvn sonar:sonar using jhipster and sonar in docker containers

Tags: docker, sonarqube, jhipster

After configuring the following docker containers for jhipster, everything's fine except sonar:

- docker run --name jhipster -w /home/jhipster/app -v ~/jhipster:/home/jhipster/app:rw -v ~/.m2:/home/jhipster/.m2:rw -p 8080:8080 -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -d -t jdubois/jhipster-docker;
- docker-compose -f src/main/docker/dev.yml up -d;
- docker-compose -f src/main/docker/sonar.yml up -d.

mvn builds the app correctly, but mvn sonar:sonar build fails with the error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project app: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar failed: SonarQube server can not be reached at http://localhost:9000. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'. Connection refused -> [Help 1]

I think that jhipster container cannot reach sonar container because the host is configured to localhost, but I can't find the parameter 'sonar.host.url' to update with the ip 192.168.99.100 of the sonar container. Do I need to configure this ip somewhere?
Do I need to configure something else on jhipster container to reach sonar container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the SonarQube Scanner for Maven, sonar properties can be configured in Maven XML settings and in the project's `pom.xml` (documentation [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-InitialSetup)).

`sonar.host.url` being not project specific, it's better defined in the global Maven settings.

```
<properties>
    <sonar.host.url>http://192.168.99.100:port</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```